# version 6100 unsupported must be 7100 or later error!

Tags: .fbx

I`ve got this problem when I want import an FBX. Object in Blender.
Did some one know how to fix it?

Comment: See if there is a nother fbx importer addon. Otherwise use a different tool to export the FBX first and then import it to blender

Comment: Um... Can I mark this as a duplicate of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801529/blender-doesnt-like-fbx-6100-files xD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: If you are using windows, Paint 3d also reads it.

Answer (score 11):

As already answered (and promptly marked as off-topic) [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28901679/)...

> Try the [Autodesk FBX Converter](https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-converter-archives). Unfortunately it is no longer
>   maintained, but it can converts many file formats, up to FBX 2013
>   format.
>
> Alternatively, if you know a bit of C++ you can write a simple
>   command-line file converter using the [FBX SDK](https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-sdk-2019-0).

You can convert older formats to a compatible format using this utility and then import it into Blender.

Comment: Autodesk FBX Converter also works for Ubuntu using wine.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 you can use Paint 3D

Workaround for 7000 FBX:

1. Open FBX 7000 in Mirosoft Paint 3D (Open with...)
2. Select all and save it as a new FBX
3. Open Blender and import the new FBX
4. Save then as OBJ

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: just open the FBX file in a 3D viewer (there should be one in Windows by default), then just save it as glTF and then you should be able to import that file into Blender.